# Solutions for an ODE

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a solution of the ODE $x'(t)=x(t)+\frac{1}{1+e^{t}}$ which has finite limit when $t\rightarrow \infty$, I already find that the solutions are $e^t \ln(1+e^t)-te^t-1$  however these solutions do not converge as $t$ goes to infinity. Any idea? thanks.

Comment: There is no initial condition, maybe we have to choose it in order for the obtained solution converge

Comment: Oh..yes sure, sorry, I made an edit to correct it.

Comment: I would say $+\infty$?

Comment: Ok ! How can we find a solution which converges as $t\rightarrow +\infty$

Comment: Find the solutions of the ODE which has finite limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$. What is the behavior of the other solutions?

Comment: we are dealing with the same ODE, and the question is to know the behavior of other solutions of that ODE

Answer (score 1):

The limit of your solution

> $$e^t \ln(1+e^t)-te^t-1$$

as $t\to \infty$ exists and finite and equals to $0$.

Comment: Yes but I found 0 (maybe I am wrong ! )

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar: In fact this is an answer. Read the question carefully and you will know why.

Comment: @downvoters: Stop these silly acts.

Comment: Mhenni, the limit is zero.  The next order term in the log cancels the $-1$.

Comment: @Braindead &Ron Gordon: The OP said that "these solutions do not converge as t goes to infinity" so I wanted to tell him that his solution does exist and finite. Do you see the point people?

Comment: I don't understand your answer: You say "the limit converges and equals to $-1$," but it's not clear what limit you're referring to. If we impose certain initial conditions on the solution (such as requiring $x(0) = 0$), the limit of the solution $x(t)$ as $t \to \infty$ is infinity, not $-1$. On the other hand, the solution satisfying $x(0) = -1$ diverges to $-\infty$. In fact, following Willie Wong's answer, the solution $x(t)$ converges to a finite limit at $\infty$ if and only if $x(0) = \ln 2 - 1$ (and moreover, that limit is $0$ and not $-1$).

Comment: I just wanted to tell him that the limit of his solution $e^t \ln(1+e^t)-te^t-1$ exists and finite as $t\to \infty$. I think this is clear.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal In that case, the limit is zero, not $-1$. (Regardless, you might want to clarify in your answer exactly what you're referring to; I at least certainly found it quite unclear).

Comment: @T.Bongers: This is a calculation mistake which is not the essence of this answer as I pointed out in my previous comment. Thanks for the comment. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome; +1.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* Starting from you specific solution, you get that

$$ e^t \ln(1+ e^t) - t e^t - 1 = e^t (\ln (1 + e^t) - \ln (e^t)) - 1 = \frac{\ln(e^{-t} + 1)}{e^{-t}} - 1 $$

which converges to $0$ as $t\to \infty$ through an application of L'Hopital.

---

*Original post follows*:

<strike>First, I don't think your solution is quite correct</strike>

Re-writing your equation as 
$$ x'(t) - x(t) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(t)} $$
we have that by integrating factors and a version of partial fractions we get
$$ e^t \frac{d}{dt}( e^{-t} x(t)) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(t)} \implies \frac{d}{dt} [\exp(-t)x(t)] = \frac{1}{\exp(t)} - \frac{1}{1 + \exp(t)} $$

The antiderivative on the right hand side can be explicitly evaluated
$$ \int e^{-t} = - e^{-t} $$
and
$$ -\int \frac{1}{1+ e^{t}} = \int \frac{- e^{-t}}{e^{-t} + 1} = \ln (1 + e^{-t}) $$

which gives us the solution, where $C$ is the constant of integration,

$$ x(t) = C e^t - 1 + \frac{\ln (1 + e^{-t})}{e^{-t}} $$

As $t\to\infty$, the final term is indeterminate. We can apply L'Hopital's rule to it, which yields by
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{(1+x)^{-1}}{1} = 1 $$

that provided the constant of integration $C = 0$ (this, of course, depends on the initial condition), the function $x(t)$ satisfies $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t) = 0$.